# How to replace div content with animation in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I need to change the content of the div (only 1 image element) with animation. Would be good if we can do it with according to direction variable. It should work as slideshow.

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', imgUrl)
.load(function() {
    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
        alert('broken image!');
    } else {
        $("#map").html(img);
    }
});
```

I tried to use this solution, but it changes the layout and it's just fading animation.

```
$('#map').fadeOut("slow", function(){
    var div = $("<div id='map'>"+img2+"</div>").hide();
    $(this).replaceWith(div);
    $('#map').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Only JQuery scripting solutions are needed. Thanks !

UPD: Can we fade in the new image WHILE fading away old one?

Comment: Not a solution but I suggest you to use class instead of the `id` because as per your code you are creating the `div` with same `id` and you are inserting it into DOM and hiding other and then there exists multiple `divs` with same `id` which is a bad practice.

Comment: Give the image an id and instead of fading the containing div apply fadeout on the image id itself.

Comment: Guruprasad, thanks, I will keep it in mind.
Waqar, ok, that should work. But any clues, how to do it using direction type animation?

Comment: You just want to replace `image url` right and to give animation you are hiding and showing the `div`? Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Not actually, I need to change image with another based on direction. For example, if up is pressed, old image should fade away upwards and new image should come up from bottom. Thats the ideal result I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the new image is loaded you can `fadeOut()` the old one and `fadeIn()` the new one:

```
var duration = 250;
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', imgUrl).css("display", "none")
.load(function() {
    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
        alert('broken image!');
    } else {
        $("#map").children().fadeOut(duration, function () {
            $("#map").html(img).children().fadeIn(duration);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but is there a way to animate them simultaneously ?

Comment: You, but you will have to position them on top of each other with `position: absolute`, or put them in an inner container next to each other and animate the container left or right. It's a bit more work if you want to do that.